# Distribution of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}$ where $X_i,Y_i$s are i.i.d Normal variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mean, moment-generating-function

> Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are i.i.d $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variables.
>
> I am interested in the distribution of $$U=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}$$

I define $$Z=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}}$$

Then, $$Z\mid (X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iY_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$

As this conditional distribution is independent of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, the unconditional distribution should also be the same. That is, I can say that $$Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$

Relating $U$ and $Z$, I have $$U=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}}$$

Now since I saw that $Z\mid (X_1,\ldots,X_n)\stackrel{d}{=}Z$, I can say that $Z$ is independent of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

So I have

$$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n}}}=\frac{T}{\sqrt n}$$, where $T$ is distributed as a $t$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.

> I think conditioning is the easiest way to see the result here. But is this a perfectly rigorous argument and is there any direct/alternative way of finding distributions of such functions of linear combinations of i.i.d Normal variables?

Comment: I think your approach looks very reasonable to me. I didn't test it myself but it might be an alternative to start with Chi-square distribution in the denominator?

Comment: This looks just like the least squares estimator in a regression without constant. It is, under the assumptions given, known to be normally distributed with mean $\beta$ (that would be zero if the $Y$ are independent of the $X$, too) and variance covariance matrix $\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$. You'd arrive at a t-distribution if you also need to estimate $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is this self-study?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings No.

Comment: What do you need this variable for? What is the problem exactly with the rigour of the argument?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I don't need it for anything. Problem was not much about rigour; I was interested in an alternative proof (if there exists one) that doesn't involve conditional distributions.

Comment: Re your independence argument: Let $(X,Y)$ be standard bivariate Normal.  Define $Z=|X|$ when $Y\ge 0$ and otherwise $Z=-|X|.$ You can easily check that the marginal distribution and conditional distributions of $Z$ (given $Y$) are standard Normal, but certainly $Z$ is not independent of $Y$!  *Equivalence in distribution is usually too weak to imply independence.*

Comment: @whuber the conditional distribution of Z given Y cannot be a standard normal: given Y, Z can only be of the same sign.

Comment: @a.arfe You are correct, thank you: in that comment I wrote "conditional" where I intended "marginal."

Comment: In the special case of $n=1$ we have $X_1Y_1/X_1^2 = Y_1 / X_1$, and the ratio of two independent standard normals [is Cauchy distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uncorrelated_central_normal_ratio).

Comment: What if you didn't define $Z$ at all. Based on your argument, $U|X_i$ is also independent of $X_1,X_2,..X_n$. So, now $U \sim N(0,1)$?

Comment: @Xi'an I think your comment is about $Z$ (which has a square root in the denominator), whereas mine is about $U$ (third line, no square root).

Answer (score 6):

Although this is a conditional argument as well, using the characteristic function is faster:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[\exp\left\{ \iota t\sum_i Y_i X_i\Big/{\sum_j X_j^2}\right\}\right] &=
\mathbb E\left[\left.\mathbb E\left[\exp\left\{\iota t Y_i X_i\Big/{\sum_j X_j^2}\right\}\right]\,\right|\,\mathbf X \right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\left.\mathbb E\left[\prod_i \exp\left\{\iota t Y_i X_i\Big/{\sum_j X_j^2}\right\}\right]\,\right|\,\mathbf X \right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\prod_i\left.\mathbb E\left[ \exp\left\{ t Y_i X_i\Big/{\sum_j X_j^2}\right\}\right]\,\right|\,\mathbf X\iota \right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\prod_i \exp\left\{- t^2 X_i^2 \Big/2\left\{\sum_j X_j^2\right\}^2\right\}\right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[ \exp\left\{- t^2 \Big/2{\sum_j X_j^2}\right\}\right]\\
\end{align*}
Invoking [Wolfram's integrator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E%28n-1%29%20exp%28-x-a%2Fx%29%2FGamma%28n%29%20between%200%20and%20infinity), this expectation is equal to
$$\int_0^∞ \zeta^{n/2 - 1} \frac{\exp(-\zeta - t^2/\zeta)}{Γ(n/2)}\ \text{d}\,\zeta = \frac{2 t^{n/2} K_{-n/2}(2 t)}{Γ(n/2)}$$
where $K_n$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. Hence, except for $n=1$ **this is not the characteristic function of the Cauchy distribution. This looks instead like the characteristic function of the [Student's $t$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).**

Comment: Do you use the independence of $X_i$ and $Y_i$ here? I don't seem to use it in my attempt, so I am thinking if this assumption changes anything.

Comment: Yes I do, when going from third to fourth line in the equation.